# Parsing xml output

Tags: python, xml

Need help in parsing xml output. I have tried the below following example from python docs , but havent been successful. Also tried xmltodict . did not help.
Could someone pls help. I seem to be missing something very basic here.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.fromstring(out)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1325, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0
>>> 
>>> 

    out = '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://w
    ww.cisco.com/nxos:7.2.0.D1.1.:ngoamal">
     <nf:data>
      <show>
       <ngoam>
        <probe>
         <statistics>
          <summary>
           <__readonly__>
            <TABLE_summary>
             <ROW_summary>
              <last-clear-summary-stats>Tue Sep 08 11:55:52.662 PDT</last-clear-summ
    ary-stats>
              <tx>1001</tx>
              <rx>1</rx>
              <timeout>0</timeout>
              <unsent>0</unsent>
              <resp-tx>0</resp-tx>
              <resp-rx>0</resp-rx>
              <resp-unsent>0</resp-unsent>
             </ROW_summary>
            </TABLE_summary>
           </__readonly__>
          </summary>
         </statistics>
        </probe>
       </ngoam>
      </show>
     </nf:data>
    </nf:rpc-reply>
    ]]>]]>
    '''
```

Thanks,
Mahendra

I changed the xml structure based on the suggestions and still have issues.

below is the output.

> > > print(out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:7.2.0.D1.1.:ngoamal">
 <nf:data>
  <show>
   <ngoam>
    <probe>
     <statistics>
      <summary>
       <__readonly__>
        <TABLE_summary>
         <ROW_summary>
          <last-clear-summary-stats>Tue Sep 08 11:55:52.662 PDT</last-clear-summary-stats>
          <tx>1001</tx>
          <rx>1</rx>
          <timeout>0</timeout>
          <unsent>0</unsent>
          <resp-tx>0</resp-tx>
          <resp-rx>0</resp-rx>
          <resp-unsent>0</resp-unsent>
         </ROW_summary>
        </TABLE_summary>
       </__readonly__>
      </summary>
     </statistics>
    </probe>
   </ngoam>
  </show>
 </nf:data>
</nf:rpc-reply>
```

> > > t = ET.fromstring(out)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1325, in XML
> > >           parser.feed(text)
> > >       xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0

Comment: May we see the code as well as your error and the data?

Comment: remove the last line of the triple-quoted text (i.e. the `]]>]]>`. It doesn't belong with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

your xml file is not written properly, because of `<last-clear-summary-stats>Tue Sep 08 11:55:52.662 PDT</last-clear-summ
    ary-stats>` replace that line with `<last-clear-summary-stats>Tue Sep 08 11:55:52.662 PDT</last-clear-summary-stats>` and remove ]]>]]

Comment: I have tried the below after making the above corrections. still have issues.

Comment: hi, could you post it to maheng3@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I get your error when the multi-line string starts with a newline:

```
out = '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"
```

This works, if you remove the newline and the `]]>]]>` at the end.  The XML document cannot have preceeding whitespace:

```
out = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:7.2.0.D1.1.:ngoamal">
     <nf:data>
      <show>
       <ngoam>
        <probe>
         <statistics>
          <summary>
           <__readonly__>
            <TABLE_summary>
             <ROW_summary>
              <last-clear-summary-stats>Tue Sep 08 11:55:52.662 PDT</last-clear-summary-stats>
              <tx>1001</tx>
              <rx>1</rx>
              <timeout>0</timeout>
              <unsent>0</unsent>
              <resp-tx>0</resp-tx>
              <resp-rx>0</resp-rx>
              <resp-unsent>0</resp-unsent>
             </ROW_summary>
            </TABLE_summary>
           </__readonly__>
          </summary>
         </statistics>
        </probe>
       </ngoam>
      </show>
     </nf:data>
    </nf:rpc-reply>
    '''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.fromstring(out)
```